# Java Rectangle Issue

Tags: java, user-interface, awt, draw, java-2d

I've created rectangle and inserted values like X,Y,width and height.When I call fillRect or drawRect, it says method fillRect is not applicable for arguments (double,double,double,double).

```
rectangle=new Rectangle(500,120,1000,20);
g.fillRect(rectangle.getX(),rectangle.getY(),rectangle.getWidth(),rectangle.getHeight());
```

This happens too when I use integer variables instead of numbers.Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`fillRect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and `drawRect` methods take `int` arguments, not `double`. You have two options:

1. If you're using `Graphics2D`, use [`g.fill(rectangle)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#fill%28java.awt.Shape%29) instead of `fillRect`.
2. Cast the arguments to `int`

   ```
   g.fillRect((int) rectangle.getX(),(int) rectangle.getY(),
              (int) rectangle.getWidth(),(int) rectangle.getHeight());
   ```